# How can I send bulk email to a single domain safely?

Tags: email, email-server

There are instances where I need to send email blasts to a single domain such `users@somesite.com`. This list can be quite large at times. In nearly all cases it's a single email and I'll likely not be sending another to that domain. I've checked the CAN-SPAM Act and I seem to be in the clear as the emails are not considered "commercial". However, I want to reduce the risk of our mail server from getting blacklisted and virtually useless.

My thought is to setup my lists (I'm using a custom email system) to send a certain number at a time such as 200 an hour or something to that effect. I'm unclear if that's a viable solution and if so I'm trying to find out an acceptable send frequency.

Comment: Contact the mail admins for that domain and get your IP/domain whitelisted and inquire if they will exclude your IP from any rate limits they may have.  Short of that, @henry's answer is absolutely correct.  Each site have their own rules, limits and behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the domain you're sending to. Different rules for different domains. Most Domains will Greylist you for a period of time, blacklisting usually occurs when users mark your emails as spam or is mal-ware is detected.

Comment: Also, note that greylisting is normally for one combination of (sender address + target address), so each single email will be subject to the greylisting delay.